# How to solve ModuleNotFoundError when installing dependencies

Tags: python, pip, cython, modulenotfounderror

I want to install these dependencies (streamlit, fbprophet, yfinance, plotly)

I run: `pip install streamlit fbprophet yfinance plotly`

It is showing this error in the terminal!

```
Collecting streamlit
  Using cached streamlit-1.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.2 MB)
Collecting fbprophet
  Using cached fbprophet-0.7.1.tar.gz (64 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting yfinance
  Using cached yfinance-0.1.85-py2.py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Collecting plotly
  Using cached plotly-5.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15.3 MB)
Collecting typing-extensions>=3.10.0.0
  Using cached typing_extensions-4.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting requests>=2.4
  Using cached requests-2.28.1-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
Collecting pympler>=0.9
  Using cached Pympler-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (164 kB)
Collecting watchdog
  Using cached watchdog-2.1.9-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (78 kB)
Collecting pandas>=0.21.0
  Using cached pandas-1.5.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (10.9 MB)
Collecting pydeck>=0.1.dev5
  Using cached pydeck-0.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.7 MB)
Collecting altair>=3.2.0
  Using cached altair-4.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (812 kB)
Collecting toml
  Using cached toml-0.10.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting importlib-metadata>=1.4
  Using cached importlib_metadata-5.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting click>=7.0
  Using cached click-8.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
Collecting pillow>=6.2.0
  Using cached Pillow-9.3.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (2.5 MB)
Collecting protobuf<4,>=3.12
  Using cached protobuf-3.20.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (904 kB)
Collecting validators>=0.2
  Using cached validators-0.20.0.tar.gz (30 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting gitpython!=3.1.19
  Using cached GitPython-3.1.29-py3-none-any.whl (182 kB)
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.23.4-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (14.7 MB)
Collecting semver
  Using cached semver-2.13.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting pyarrow>=4.0
  Using cached pyarrow-10.0.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (20.0 MB)
Collecting python-dateutil
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
Collecting blinker>=1.0.0
  Using cached blinker-1.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting packaging>=14.1
  Using cached packaging-21.3-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
Collecting rich>=10.11.0
  Using cached rich-12.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (237 kB)
Collecting tornado>=5.0
  Using cached tornado-6.2-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl (425 kB)
Collecting cachetools>=4.0
  Using cached cachetools-5.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (9.3 kB)
Collecting tzlocal>=1.1
  Using cached tzlocal-4.2-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Collecting Cython>=0.22
  Using cached Cython-0.29.32-py2.py3-none-any.whl (986 kB)
Collecting cmdstanpy==0.9.5
  Using cached cmdstanpy-0.9.5-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
Collecting pystan>=2.14
  Using cached pystan-3.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting matplotlib>=2.0.0
  Using cached matplotlib-3.6.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (7.2 MB)
Collecting LunarCalendar>=0.0.9
  Using cached LunarCalendar-0.0.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting convertdate>=2.1.2
  Using cached convertdate-2.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (47 kB)
Collecting holidays>=0.10.2
  Using cached holidays-0.16-py3-none-any.whl (184 kB)
Collecting setuptools-git>=1.2
  Using cached setuptools_git-1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting tqdm>=4.36.1
  Using cached tqdm-4.64.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (78 kB)
Collecting multitasking>=0.0.7
  Using cached multitasking-0.0.11-py3-none-any.whl (8.5 kB)
Collecting appdirs>=1.4.4
  Using cached appdirs-1.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.6 kB)
Collecting lxml>=4.5.1
  Using cached lxml-4.9.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (3.6 MB)
Collecting tenacity>=6.2.0
  Using cached tenacity-8.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Collecting toolz
  Using cached toolz-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl (55 kB)
Collecting entrypoints
  Using cached entrypoints-0.4-py3-none-any.whl (5.3 kB)
Collecting jinja2
  Using cached Jinja2-3.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting jsonschema>=3.0
  Using cached jsonschema-4.17.0-py3-none-any.whl (83 kB)
Collecting colorama
  Using cached colorama-0.4.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Collecting pymeeus<=1,>=0.3.13
  Using cached PyMeeus-0.5.11.tar.gz (5.4 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting gitdb<5,>=4.0.1
  Using cached gitdb-4.0.9-py3-none-any.whl (63 kB)
Collecting korean-lunar-calendar
  Using cached korean_lunar_calendar-0.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (9.0 kB)
Collecting hijri-converter
  Using cached hijri_converter-2.2.4-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting zipp>=0.5
  Using cached zipp-3.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.2 kB)
Collecting ephem>=3.7.5.3
  Using cached ephem-4.1.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (1.4 MB)
Collecting pytz
  Using cached pytz-2022.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (498 kB)
Collecting contourpy>=1.0.1
  Using cached contourpy-1.0.6-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (161 kB)
Collecting fonttools>=4.22.0
  Using cached fonttools-4.38.0-py3-none-any.whl (965 kB)
Collecting kiwisolver>=1.0.1
  Using cached kiwisolver-1.4.4-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (55 kB)
Collecting pyparsing>=2.2.1
  Using cached clikit-0.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (91 kB)
Collecting pystan>=2.14
  Using cached pystan-3.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
  Using cached pystan-3.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
  Using cached pystan-3.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
  Using cached pystan-3.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cpz50fug\pystan_29b2e0ee589444e48d57493b846dbeee\setup.py", line 122, in <module>
          from Cython.Build.Inline import _get_build_extension
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

How do I solve this? I tried on different devices it is showing more errors... I used anaconda navigator to run this project.

Comment: Please try to read the error message first. Seems like you haven,t installed Cython which is a requirement for pystan

Comment: Note that it's `pip install prophet` (not **fb**prophet) - https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/installation.html#installation-in-python

Answer (score -1):

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'`

You need Cython inorder to install pystan